# Not able to load details based on applied filters in ajax and laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, yajra-datatable

I am new to Laravel and ajax and I am trying to apply Custom filters on Table data. I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmUH049dk9I but unfortunately it's not working. I have used yajra data tables.
Here is my controller code.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class CustomSearchController extends Controller
{
    function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(request()->ajax())
        {
            if(!empty($request->Business_unit))
            {
                $data = DB::table('memberdetails')
                        ->select('membersid','Role','Region','Orglevel1','Orglevel2')
                        ->where('Business_unit',$request->Business_unit)
                        ->get();
            }
            else
            {
                $data = DB:: table('memberdetails')
                        ->select('membersid','Role','Region','Orglevel1','Orglevel2')
                        ->get();
            }
            return datatables()->of($data)->make(true);
        }
        $Business_unit = DB::table('memberdetails')
                            ->select('Business_unit')
                            ->groupBy('Business_unit')
                            ->orderBy('Business_unit', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        return view('admin.members.test', compact('Business_unit'));
    }
}
```

This is my view

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="Business_unit" id="Business_unit" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Business Unit</option>
                @foreach($Business_unit as $Bu)
                <option value="{{ $Bu->Business_unit }}">{{ $Bu->Business_unit}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>           
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary rounded" type="button" id="search" name="search">Apply</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary rounded" type="button" id="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="members_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Employee ID
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Role
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%">
                    Region
                </th>
                <th style="width: 12%">
                  Org Level1
                </th>
                <th style="width: 12%">
                   Org Level2
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
@endsection
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    fill_datable();

    function fill_datable(Business_unit = ''){
      var datatable = $('members_data').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        ajax:{
          url:{{ "route('CustomSearch.index')" }},
          data:{ Business_unit:Business_unit }
        },
        columns: [
          {
            data: 'membersid',
            name: 'membersid'
          },
          {
            data: 'Role',
            name: 'Role'
          },
          {
            data: 'Region',
            name: 'Region'
          },
          {
            data: 'Orglevel1',
            name: 'Orglevel1'
          },
          {
            data: 'Orglevel2',
            name: 'Orglevel2'
          },
        ]
      });
    }

    $('#search').click(function()
    {
      var Business_unit = $('#Business_unit').val();
      if( Business_unit != '')
      {
        $('#members_data').DataTable().destroy();
        fill_datable(Business_unit);
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Select Business Unit Filter');
      }
    });

    $('#reset').click(function(){
      $('#Business_unit').val();
      $('#members_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fill_datable();
    });
  });
 </script>
```

and this is the route

```html
Route::get('/test', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomSearchController::class, 'index'])->name('test');
```

Not sure what is missing... I am able to load the Business units in dropdown but the data is not loading and nor the filters are getting applied. Can someone help me out in this?

Comment: In index method simple return view with main data and create another method for all operations

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya I am able to fetch all the records in table but when I choose apply filter only 10 records are shown for any value I choose same top 10 records...any suggestions?